# Restrict comment resolution in TFS to author only

Tags: tfs, pull-request

It is possible to set branch policy to require comment resolution before pull request can be completed. However, it seems that anyone - not just the comment author - is able to set comment status to "Resolved" and therefore complete the pull request effectively circumventing the policy.

Is there a way to restrict that and configure the system so that only comment author is able to set it's status to "Resolved"?

Comment: Also interested in this